# What is the AT command to retrieve a wireless modem static IP?

Tags: modem, static-ip

Set up with Verizon on a private network.  Each wireless modem is assigned a static IP address and MDN from the Verizon network.  Is there an AT command string that will retrieve this IP address from the modem?

Answer (score 0):

The AT commands configure the modem in respect to the line (OSI layers 1 and 2), not in terms of the data you run on top. But IP is a layer-3 protocol, and its addressing is configured using different mechanisms (e.g. DHCP, or fixed assignments). So you need to check these mechanisms instead.